# Nesting events within Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, tone.js

I am creating multiple toggle buttons on a site that is using ToneJS.  Basically, I want the different buttons to play different tracks.

I have created the two identical buttons like this.

Button 1:

```
function togglePlay() {
  const status = Tone.Transport.state; // Is either 'started', 'stopped' or 'paused'
  const element = document.getElementById("play-stop-toggle");
  if (status == "started") {
    element.innerText = "PLAY";
    Tone.Transport.stop()
  } else {
    element.innerText = "STOP";
    Tone.Transport.start()
  }

  document.querySelector('#status').textContent = status;
}
```

Button 2:

```
function togglePlay2() {
  const status = Tone.Transport.state; // Is either 'started', 'stopped' or 'paused'
  const element = document.getElementById("play-stop-toggle2");
  if (status == "started") {
    element.innerText = "PLAY";
    Tone.Transport.stop()
  } else {
    element.innerText = "STOP";
    Tone.Transport.start()
  }

  document.querySelector('#status').textContent = status;
}
```

Currently they are playing the same loop, because the below code is defined globally:

```
var filter = new Tone.Filter({
  type: 'lowpass',
  Q: 12
}).toMaster()


var synth = new Tone.MembraneSynth().toMaster()

//create a loop
var loop = new Tone.Loop(function(time){
    synth.triggerAttackRelease("A1", "8n", time)
}, "2n")


//play the loop between 0-2m on the transport
loop.start(0)
// loop.start(0).stop('2m')
```

How would I nest the `filter`, `synth`, and `loop` within each `function togglePlay()` so that I could define different sounds depending on which button is toggled?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question properly, but if `filter`, `synth`, and `loop` are defined globally, then both your functions `togglePlay()` and `togglePlay2()` have access to them. You can define any number of filters, loops, etc. globally and the function for each button can call the ones you want to associate with it. What is the issue?

Comment: @EvanMorrison - Right.  My question is super basic.  I am asking a really simple question about how to -- as a syntax level -- remove them from the global context and nest them within the functions.

Comment: Ah, ok, then can you not literally put the global code inside the toggle functions, with different options for each? Do they conflict somehow? I don't know anything about the API for Tone. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any problem with doing this?

```
function togglePlay() {
  const status = Tone.Transport.state; // Is either 'started', 'stopped' or 'paused'
  const element = document.getElementById("play-stop-toggle");
  if (status == "started") {
    element.innerText = "PLAY";
    Tone.Transport.stop()
  } else {
    element.innerText = "STOP";
    var filter = new Tone.Filter({
       type: 'lowpass',
       Q: 12
    }).toMaster()

    var synth = new Tone.MembraneSynth().toMaster()

    //create a loop
    var loop = new Tone.Loop(function(time){
        synth.triggerAttackRelease("A1", "8n", time)
    }, "2n")

    //play the loop between 0-2m on the transport
    loop.start(0)
    // loop.start(0).stop('2m')
    Tone.Transport.start()
  }

  document.querySelector('#status').textContent = status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that allows multiple tones simultaneously. You have to do more state management if you want one tone starting to stop any others that are currently running. This code gives you the idea of how you bind context-specific configuration to a click handler to specialise the behaviour of a button.

I don't know [Tone](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/r12/Transport), however, and your code doesn't have the full setup, so you *may* need to do more to give each handler its own Tone instance.

```js
function createTogglePlayClickhandler(config) {
    var filter = new Tone.Filter(config.filter).toMaster()
    var synth = config.synth
      //create a loop
    var loop = config.loop
    const element = document.getElementById(elementId);

    return function togglePlay() {
        const status = Tone.Transport.state; // Is either 'started', 'stopped' or 'paused'
        
        if (status == "started") {
        element.innerText = "PLAY";
        Tone.Transport.stop()
        } else {
        element.innerText = "STOP";
        Tone.Transport.start()
        }
    
        document.querySelector('#status').textContent = status;
    }
}

// Generate click handlers
createTogglePlayClickhandler({ 
    elementId: "play-stop-toggle",
    filter: {
        type: 'lowpass',
        Q: 12
      },
    synth: new Tone.MembraneSynth().toMaster(),
    loop: new Tone.Loop(function(time){
        synth.triggerAttackRelease("A1", "8n", time)
    }, "2n")
});
createTogglePlayClickhandler({ 
    elementId: "play-stop-toggle2",
    filter: {
        type: 'lowpass',
        Q: 12
      },
    synth: new Tone.MembraneSynth().toMaster(),
    loop: new Tone.Loop(function(time){
        synth.triggerAttackRelease("A1", "8n", time)
    }, "2n")
});
```

It looks like you have a single status element, so I think the behaviour you want is one tone at a time? So if I click Tone A, then click Tone B, Tone B should start, and Tone A should stop?

Or do you want multi-timbre?

Comment: I am trying to achieve the first thing you suggested -- i.e. if Tone B is activated, Tone A should stop.